Ray + lightning prepare_data_loader MisconfigurationException
I am trying to start a training session with Ray on GPU but experiencing errors while on CPU everything works smoothly. The issues are raising from the data modules:
I have the following class which inherits from LightningDataModule:
class ProteinsDataModule(LightningDataModule):

    def __init__(self,
                 csv_data: str,
                 max_length: int = None,
                 train_val_split: Tuple[float, float] = (0.9, 0.1),
                 train_batch_size: int = 32,
                 valid_batch_size: int = 32,
                 num_workers: int = 1,
                 seed: int = 0,
                 min_fitness: int = 0,
                 auto_transfer: bool = False, 
                 base_dataloader = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.save_hyperparameters(logger=False)
        self.name = "ProteinDataLoader"
        self.multiprocessing_context = None
        self.train_dataset = None
        self.valid_dataset = None
        self.auto_transfer = auto_transfer
        self.base_dataloader = base_dataloader
        self.datasets = ProteinDataset(self.hparams.csv_data,
                                       self.hparams.max_length)
        self.setup()

    @property
    def min_fitness(self):
        return self.datasets.min_fitness

    @property
    def max_length(self):
        return self.datasets.max_length

    def set_max_length(self, max_len: int):
        self.datasets.max_length = max_len

    def setup(self) -> None:
        self.train_dataset, self.valid_dataset = random_split(
            dataset=self.datasets,
            lengths=self.hparams.train_val_split,
            generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(self.hparams.seed)
        )

    def train_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        train_loader =  DataLoader(
            dataset=self.train_dataset,
            batch_size=self.hparams.train_batch_size,
            num_workers=self.hparams.num_workers,
            shuffle=False,
            # pin_memory=True,
            # persistent_workers=True
        )
        return train_loader

    def val_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        val_loader = DataLoader(
            dataset=self.valid_dataset,
            batch_size=self.hparams.valid_batch_size,
            num_workers=self.hparams.num_workers,
            shuffle=False,
            # pin_memory=True,
            # persistent_workers=True
        )
        return val_loader

In my main train function I do the following:
log.info(f"Instantiating training data <{cfg.data._target_}>")
    datamodule: LightningDataModule = hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg.data)
    log.info("Started creating train_loader")
    train_loader = ray.train.torch.prepare_data_loader(datamodule.train_dataloader(), auto_transfer=False)
    log.info("Finished creating train_loader")
    val_loader = ray.train.torch.prepare_data_loader(datamodule.val_dataloader(),auto_transfer=False)

which I pass like the following:
trainer.fit(
            model, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader
        )

I keep on getting the following error:
lightning.fabric.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: 
Trying to inject custom `Sampler` into the `_WrappedDataLoader` instance.
This would fail as some of the `__init__` arguments are not available as instance attributes.
The missing attributes are ['auto_transfer', 'base_dataloader']. 
If you instantiate your `_WrappedDataLoader` inside a `*_dataloader` hook of your module, we will do this for you.
Otherwise, define `self.auto_transfer`, `self.base_dataloader` inside your `__init__`.

I tried downgrading both torch and ray versions, changing values and adding to the wrapped loader.
